# Pass additional props through hookrouter

Tags: reactjs, hookrouter

I'm trying to pass additional data through to a component using [hookrouter](https://github.com/Paratron/hookrouter/blob/master/src-docs/pages/en/02_routing.md#passing-additional-data-to-route-functions). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I get the error `Functions are not valid as React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render.`

Path: `Routes`

```
const routes = {
  "/modules/unit/:id": ({ id }) => (page_url) => (
    <UnitPage unit_id={id} page_url={page_url} />
  )
};
```

Path: `Link within page`

```
<A href={`modules/unit/${id}`} page_url={page_url}>
  Unit link
</A>
```

** UPDATE **

Path `UnitPage.jsx`

```
class UnitPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("props", this.props);
  }

  render() {
    const { id, page_url } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{id}</p>
        <p>{page_url}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `UnitPage`? Also you shouldn't be using snake case in JSX; that can lead to other issues. JS uses camelCase.

Comment: @rschristian see update

Comment: @bp123 the error should be due to `"/modules/unit/:id": ({ id }) => (page_url) => (
    <UnitPage unit_id={id} page_url={page_url} />)`. You are returning a function here instead of a component